# Hibernate EntityManager.remove(entity) deletes record from database and association but not from entity collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So, i have 2 entities **Project** & **TaskPlan**, inside Project entity i have a **@ManyToMany** association with the **TaskPlan** entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {     
@Column(name = "descriptions")
private String descriptions;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "project_has_task_plan",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_plan_id")})
private Set<TaskPlan> taskPlans;

public Set<TaskPlan> getTaskPlans() {
    return taskPlans;
}

public void setTaskPlans(Set<TaskPlan> taskPlans) {
    this.taskPlans = taskPlans;
}

....
@Entity
@Table(name = "task_plan")
public class TaskPlan {

@GeneratedValue(generator = "idIncrementor")
@GenericGenerator(name = "idIncrementor", strategy = "increment")
@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;...
```

I am using DAO methods to interract with both entities and i have a **@PersitenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)**.I am using generics also to get entity by id

```
  public T getById (Long id) {
    if (id==null) {
        return null;

    } else {

        Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("from " + type.getName() + " where id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        List<T> result = query.getResultList();
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
                return result.get(0);

        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not found!");
    }

}
```

I am updating taskplans collection on Project entity using the following method and adding a new element to **taskPlans** Set

```
//ProjectService class
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseBody
public void updateProject(@RequestBody Project project) throws Exception {
    this.projectFacade.updateOne(project);
}
 //ProjectFacade class
@Override
public void updateOne(Project project) {
    Project itemFromDbs = this.projectDao.getById(project.getId());
    if (itemFromDbs != null) {
        itemFromDbs.setName(project.getName());
        itemFromDbs.setDescriptions(project.getDescriptions());
        if (project.getTaskPlans() != null) {
            project.getTaskPlans().stream().forEach(taskPlan -> {
                TaskPlan taskPlanToAdd = taskplanDao.getById(taskPlan.getId());
                if (taskPlanToAdd == null) {
                    itemFromDbs.getTaskPlans().add(taskPlan);
                }
            });
        }
        this.projectDao.updateProject(itemFromDbs);
    }
}
....
 //ProjectDao class
 @Transactional
public void updateProject(Project project) {
    Project itemFromDbs = this.getById(project.getId());
    if (itemFromDbs != null) {
        itemFromDbs.setTaskPlans(project.getTaskPlans());
        entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evictAll();
        entityManager.persist(itemFromDbs);

        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.clear();
    }
}
```

Everything works fine for the moment, the bad thing comes when i try to remove a taskplan from **TaskPlan** entity..**.entitymanager.remove()** works fine, the entity gets removed from the **TaskPlan table** and the associated **project_has_task_plan** table, but when i refresh the page and **getById** on **Project** entity gets triggerd the deleted item from **TaskPlan** entity is still inside **Set taskplans**...

I have to mention that **second-level cache is completly disabled** and **clear()** or **evictAll()** methods does not work.

Here is the removal code:

```
 //TaskPlanService class
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}",method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseBody
public void deleteTaskPlan(@PathVariable("id") Long taskPlanId) throws Exception {
    this.taskplanFacade.deleteOne(taskPlanId);
}

 //TaskPlanFacade class
 public void deleteOne(Long taskPlanId) {
    taskplanDao.deleteById(taskPlanId);
}
 //TaskPlanDao class
@Transactional
@Override
public void deleteById(Long taskPlanId) {
    TaskPlan taskPlanFromDbs=this.getById(taskPlanId);
    if(taskPlanFromDbs!=null){
        taskPlanFromDbs.getTasks().stream().forEach(task -> {//this things
                      //are associated with the                            
                     //taskplan entity but for the moment i don't interract   
                    //with them
            task.getBadges().stream().forEach(badge -> {
                entityManager.remove(badge);
            });
            entityManager.remove(task);
        });
        taskPlanFromDbs.getBadges().stream().forEach(badge -> {
            entityManager.remove(badge);
        });
        entityManager.remove(taskPlanFromDbs);
        entityManager.flush();

        entityManager.clear();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED 
 I have set the @PersitenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION) 
then inside ProjectDao class :

```
@Transactional
public void updateProject(Project project) {
    Project itemFromDbs = this.getById(project.getId());
    if (itemFromDbs != null) {
        itemFromDbs.setTaskPlans(project.getTaskPlans());
        entityManager.merge(itemFromDbs);//so i wont persist a detached entity
        entityManager.flush();
    }
}
```

Changed also the Project & TaskPlan entities asociation fetchType option so i wont get a lazy initialization error:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
@GeneratedValue(generator = "idIncrementor")
@GenericGenerator(name = "idIncrementor", strategy = "increment")
@Id
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "descriptions")
private String descriptions;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "project_has_task_plan",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "project_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "task_plan_id")})
private Set<TaskPlan> taskPlans;
```

Thanks @fdreger :)

Answer (score 2):

As a developer you are responsible for maintaining of all the relationships of your entity. So if you delete a `TaskPlan` you must take care of removing it from any associations with other entities.

[JPA 2.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) *2.9 EntityRelationships*:

> Note that it is the application that bears responsibility for maintaining the consistency of runtime relationships — for example, for insuring that the “one” and the “many” sides of a bidirectional relationship are consistent with one another when the application updates the relationship at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

[disclosure: I have NOT debugged, tried to execute or even deeply read your code; I have no idea how the EntityManager is created or which @Transactional you are using]

Hibernate (and other JPA providers) generally do not modify entities once they are fetched - there is no magic attached to your objects, you are still free to use custom collections etc. There is no reason for anything to disappear from or appear inside your collections.

The concept of using JPA is based on the "Unit Of Work" pattern, which mandates splitting operations into separate "chunks of business logic" and running each of those chunks in a separate EntityManager. Syncing with the database only happens when the whole piece of work is finished and the EntityManager is closed (at least in the mental model; implementations work differently) when the chunk of work is done.

By using an extended entity manager the code you show throws monkey wrench into the machinery. The sources seem to misuse Hibernate and probably has many problems, both logical and connected to concurrency. It could be easily fixed and simplified by using a normal, transactional entity manager.

Comment: i have tried to use transactional entity manager but then i will need to set my Set<TaskPlan> taskPlans to a EAGER fetchType, and i really want to avoid that

Comment: @IonutCringanu This is putting cart before the horse. I strongly believe it's wrong to make the whole program both incorrect and quirky (and just how do you synchronize access your collections?!), just because we don't like the name of one of the configuration option. What are you actually trying to avoid? How many database reads are you actually ready to perform? How much stale data are you ready to accept?